# listView don't update

Tags: android, listview, refresh, adapter

I have a problem, please help.  I want `ListView` to update (refresh) each time I click on the radio button.  Any useful help will be welcomed.

```
public class thirdActivity  extends Activity {

SQLiteDatabase db;
String date, gorivo, kolicina, cijena, litra, ID, gor;
Integer index=0;
RadioButton vozilo1, vozilo2, vozilo3;
int vozilo= 1;


public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
ListViewAdapter adapter=new ListViewAdapter(this, list);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.third);

     ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    populateList();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     ListViewAdapter adapter=new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    vozilo1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio000);        
    vozilo2    = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio100);
    vozilo3    = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio200);


    OnClickListener listenervoz1 = new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vozilo=1;
            populateList();
        }

    };

    OnClickListener listenervoz2 = new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vozilo=2;
            populateList();



        }
        };

    OnClickListener listenervoz3 = new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vozilo=3;

            populateList(); 

        }};


    Button btnvoz1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radio000);
    btnvoz1.setOnClickListener(listenervoz1);
    Button btnvoz2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radio100);
    btnvoz2.setOnClickListener(listenervoz2);
    Button btnvoz3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radio200);
    btnvoz3.setOnClickListener(listenervoz3);

}
public void populateList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Integer i = null;
    TextView ukupnoCijena = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ukupno_cijena);
    TextView ukupnoKolicina = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ukupnoKolicina);
    TextView tridesetCijena = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tridesetCijena);
    TextView tridesetKolicina = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tridesetkol);
    //TextView sveUkupnoC= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ukupno_cijena0);
    //TextView sveUkupnoK = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ukupnoKolicina0);
    list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "ID");
        temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "DATUM");
        temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "KOLICINA l");
        temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "CIJENA Kn");
        temp.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, "Go");
    list.add(temp);


    db=openOrCreateDatabase("PotrosnjaDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS potrosnjaDB (" +
            "ID         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            "datum      DATE ," +
            "gorivo     VARCHAR(10) ,"+
            "kolicina   NUMBER ," +
            "cijena     DECIMAL(4,2) ," +
            "vozilo     NUMBER)"
            );

    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM potrosnjaDB where vozilo="+vozilo+"  ;", null);

    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {

        for ( i= c.getCount(); i>0; i--) {
            ID=c.getString(0);
            date= c.getString(1).replace("-", ".");
            gor =c.getString(2).substring(0, 2);
            cijena = c.getString(3);
            kolicina = c.getString(4);

            HashMap<String, String> temp1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            temp1.put(FIRST_COLUMN, ID); //
            temp1.put(SECOND_COLUMN, date); //
            temp1.put(THIRD_COLUMN,  cijena);
            temp1.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, kolicina); //
            temp1.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, gor);
            list.add(temp1);
            c.moveToNext();


        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(thirdActivity.this, "Podaci nisu uneseni", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    c=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(cijena) FROM potrosnjaDB where vozilo="+vozilo+" ;", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            ukupnoCijena.setText(c.getString(0)+ " kn.");
        }
        else {showMessage("Greška", "Podaci nisu pronađeni");}

    c=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(kolicina) FROM potrosnjaDB where vozilo="+vozilo+"   ;", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            ukupnoKolicina.setText(c.getString(0)+ " lit.");
        }
        else {showMessage("Greška", "Podaci nisu pronađeni");}


        c=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(cijena) FROM potrosnjaDB where datum >= date('now', '-30 days') AND vozilo="+vozilo+"   ;", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {   
            tridesetCijena.setText(c.getString(0)+ " kn.");
        }
        else {showMessage("Greška", "Podaci nisu pronađeni");}

        c=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(kolicina) FROM potrosnjaDB where datum >= date('now', '-30 days') AND vozilo="+vozilo+"   ;", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {   
            tridesetKolicina.setText(c.getString(0)+ " lit.");
        }
        else {showMessage("Greška", "Podaci nisu pronađeni");}  


        /*c=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(cijena) FROM potrosnjaDB ;", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            sveUkupnoC.setText(c.getString(0)+ " kn.");
        }
        else {showMessage("Greška", "Podaci nisu pronađeni");}

    c=db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(kolicina) FROM potrosnjaDB ;", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            sveUkupnoK.setText(c.getString(0)+ " lit.");
        }
        else {showMessage("Greška", "Podaci nisu pronađeni");} */


}
private void showMessage(String title, String message) {        
    Builder builder=new Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
    }
```

}

If I click radio 1 I want `ListView` to show data from `SQLite` for `vozilo1`, `rado2` for `vozilo2`, etc.

Comment: Can you explain your code a bit more. Where is the radio button? Is it within a listitem ?

Comment: radio button group is on same activity... every one have own listener and change variable int vozilo. problem is when i click on radio button, variable change, textViews and everything else  update their content and show right things... but listView don't.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` **every** time you change the Model for your `ListView`.

I notice that in your `OnClickListener`, you change your `vozilo` variable (which really should be passed into your `populateList()` method as an argument, by the way), call `populateList()`, but never let your adapter know that your list changed.

Comment: you said that i need in method populate(int vozilo) for each row i update call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ?